# Bind to SHOW CREATE TABLE result inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I need to create a new table based on existing one. Using `Create table like` do not create constraints.

In order to work around this I tried to do it with a stored procedure.

```
set @a = concat("SHOW CREATE TABLE ", tableName);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a ;
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Now I want to take the output of 'EXECUTE stmt1' change the table name and execute it, ending with a deep copy of the original table structure.

I want to do it only with Mysql script, I know how to do it with bash, golang, Java, PHP, ...

1. Can I read the "session standard output" right after I run the execute command?
2. Can I get the output of a stored procedure when using CALL. For example:

   ```
   set res = call createCopy(tableName)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read the cell from the SHOW statement result using SQL (MySQL) script.

I'd suggest you to use [CREATE TABLE with SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) command. It will do the trick.

From the *CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax* documentation:

> You can create one table from another by adding a SELECT statement at
>   the end of the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Not good. Create table LIKE, create indexes but no constraints. Create SELECT create no indexes.

Comment: There is a HARD way for SQL: read metadata from `information_schema` tables, construct CREATE TABLE statement, and then execute it.

Comment: From the other hand, why not to do it in application?

Comment: The goal is to "clean" production DB from 0.5 Tera to ~50MB.  The less dependency the better. So, the plan was, load SQL script to the database, run it and delete the cleaning function at the end. Pure cross platform solution. But maybe bash dependency is not so bad.

Comment: If I understand, you need to truncate some tables, right?

Comment: I need to delete 95% of a 30 million rows table. The fast way to do it is to clone the table structure, insert filtered data from the original table to the clone table, drop the original table and rename the clone table to the original table name.

Comment: Table's design is unchanged, so, you may write static CREATE TABLE statement in procedure; just create it, then populate and rename.

Comment: DB structure change a lot. Otherwise I wouldn’t have a problem. I want to clean production DB without the need to maintain the schema.

Answer (score 0):

The way it looks now, there are two ways to solve this.
1. Use `CREATE LIKE` and maintain the constraints separately.
2. Use BASH